# Does using an smtp relay help preventing your email going into spam?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

Does using an smtp relay such as google's smtp-relay.gmail.com prevent (or at least help) your emails not going into the spam folder on the recipient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it could help, because `smtp-relay.gmail.com` might look more trustworthy for your recepients then unknown SMTP server even properly configured. Just don't forget to add `SPF` record for your domain which will tell recepients that `smtp-relay.gmail.com` is authorized to send mail from your domain.